# Access existing IE11 with pywin32

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, pywin32, pywinauto, pywin

I am trying my hand at automation, currently playing around with pywin32, but I was wondering if it is possible to interact with a window of Internet Explorer 11 that I manually opened.

I ask because I am working within a specific intranet and think it would be more trouble than it would be worth to go through a new IE window, access the intranet's file system, download their copy of the browser, and finally open it.

Thank you!